# Variable in swift

Tags: swift, xcode, oop, swiftui

Is it safe to say that there are two types of variable in Swift ?

1. variable
2. Constant

Can constant be reffered to as a type of variable?

I ask this question because in programming world, *variable can be define as data container (way to hold and store data)*.

Need more light shed on this to clear all doubt.

Comment: [Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)) and [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)) definitions according to Wikipedia

Comment: The [language](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html#ID310) clearly separates declaration into variables and constants, so what's your actual question here? `variable can be define as data container` - both variables and constants can be containers/collections, can you update the question with more details about what's unclear to you?

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, a constant and a variable are two different types of data containers that are declared with different keywords, `let` and `var` respectively. So a constant is not a type of variable.

A variable is a data container whose value can be changed.  A constant is a data container whose value is set once and can never be changed.